# Text-based file navigator with search as you type

Tags: file-browser

How do I set up Midnight Commander or other text-based file navigator so that when I start typing it searches the first directory or file matching the typed text?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean "search for", not "search in".

If you want to use tab autocompletion with `mc` on the command line, use **alt-tab** (or **ctrl-alt-tab** if that doesn't work) instead of tab.

If you press **ctrl-s**, you'll see a highlighted search bar replace the "mini-status" bar at the bottom of your current panel.  When you start typing, the selection bar will jump to the first matching file name (so, e.g., you can just hit 'm' to go to files starting with m).  **Esc** closes the bar.

Comment: uu, nice. How do I make Ctrl-S always-on?